# Open item from ios push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have basic push notification set up done and I am receiving the push notification in my app. Using parse as backend.

Now I want to open the specific item from the app when tapping on notification. But not sure how to approach.

I am sending itemID in the notification payload.

After reading some documentation I understand that I need to write code in following two delegate methods mainly when the app is active and Inactive.

1. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
   when tapping on the notification if app is not active (i.e. not open or in background) I want the sync to finish first and then navigate user to the itemsDetailViewController and shoe item based on itemID.
2. didReceiveRemoteNotification
   when app is open I want to directly navigate to item based on the itemID in push notification. I am able to see the key/value pair of custom data I am sending in push notification. But not sure what to do next. How do I pass this itemID to the next controller and open item.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. The function `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is the point where you should handle the notification. However it is up to you to `deep link` to where you would like to.

You can do something like a modal.

```
let aViewController = YourViewController()

aViewController.itemID = itemID

UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController.presentViewController(aViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```